# Show $p(x_n)$ $\rightarrow$ $p(x)$ for a convergent sequence $\{ x_n \}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, polynomials, proof-writing

Let there be a series such that $\{ x_n \} \rightarrow x$ and $p(x)$ be a polynomial.

Show $p(x_n)$ $\rightarrow$ $p(x)$.

> Attempt at solution:

Let $p(x)= a_nx^m+a_{n-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_1 x+ a_o$.

Since $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ we have $n \ge N_0 \Rightarrow |x_n-x|< \epsilon$.

Also since $\lim(a_n)=a$ $\ $implies $c \lim(a_n)= ca$ it follows for **(1)** $n\ge N_0$ implies $|ca_n-ca|\lt \epsilon$.

Using **(1)** we choose $n\ge N_1 \Rightarrow |a_nx^m -a_n(x_n)^m|< \frac{\epsilon}{n} $, and $n\ge N_2 \Rightarrow |a_{n-1}x^{m-1} -a_{n-1}(x_n)^{m-1})|< \frac{\epsilon}{n}$, ..., and choose $n\ge N_n$ $\Rightarrow |a_1x^{1} -a_1(x_n)^{1})|< \frac{\epsilon}{n}$

$\ $

Now taking $n \ge M \ge \max\{N_1,N_2,..., N_n\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $|p(x_n)-p(x)|$ equals to  $$ |(a_nx^m+a_{n-1}x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_1 x+ a_o) - (a_n(x_n)^m+a_{n-1}(x_n)^{m-1} + \cdots + a_1 (x_n)+ a_o)|$$

$$\le |a_nx^m -a_n(x_n)^m|+ |a_{n-1}x^{m-1} -a_{n-1}(x_n)^{m-1}|+ \cdots + |a_1 x- a_1 (x_n)^1|+|a_0-a_0|$$

$$\lt (\frac{\epsilon}{n} + \frac{\epsilon}{n}+ \cdots + \frac{\epsilon}{n}) = n\frac{\epsilon}{n} = \epsilon$$

> Question: Is my solution correct? If not where have I made mistakes and can someone provide the correct proof? And is there anything I can do write a "neater" or better proof? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: This is correct. More easily, if you show that the sum and the product of two continuous functions is continuous, then you are done. You may see your polynomial function as a linear combination of powers of the identity function $x\rightarrow x$, which is continuous.

Comment: This is an immediate corollary of the theorems dealing with algebra of limits.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In what way do you mean?

Comment: Algebra of limits deals with the theorems like limit of a finite sum/product is equal to sum/product of limits. Now $p(x_n) $ is made by sums and product involving constants and $x_n$ and hence the limit of $p(x_n) $ should be made in similar manner from the sums and products involving the limit $x$ and thus equal $p(x) $.

Comment: Using the quotient rule you can also see that the result holds if $ p$ denotes a rational function provided the denominator of $p$ does not vanish at $x$.

Comment: I have this same question for homework, I'm wondering how you could prove it with mathematical induction. How would you solve the base case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems right, but here's a much more elegant and short proof.

Recall by definition $f$ is continuous if and only if for every $x_n \rightarrow x$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.

It is clear by the equivalent $\epsilon - \delta$ definition that any constant $c$ is also continuous.

In addition, we claim $x$ is continuous, which follows from letting $\delta = \epsilon$.

Then let $f(x) =\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k x^k$ be a polynomial, then we see that we can form $f(x)$ by multiplying and adding constants and $x$. Hence, as finite products and additions of continuous functions are continuous, we see $f$ is continuous. Hence, by definition for all $x_n \rightarrow x$, $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.